# smb.conf configured with SMBCLIENT?

Tags: ubuntu, windows, smb-conf

I am getting the error NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME  when I send the command echo "hello" | smbclient -M "hostname" from Ubuntu to Window. Dumb question, do I need to to configure smb.conf?

Comment: Not necessarily, but in case there is authentication going on, you might have to feed smbclient with more parameters than just `-M` (e.g. `-U`).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a silly question but are you sure your netbios client is running winpopup??? Because smbclient -M is aimed at sending messages to winpopup only AFAICT.

This is a pretty old protocol which has been abandonned after win95 IIRC...
See [Q137143](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137143) from MS Kb and man smbclient to make sure what you do is acheivable with the version of samba and windows you're using.

Comment: My NetBIOS client is on Window's 8. My guess is that Smbclient -M is will not work. What other options to send message between Ubuntu 13.10 and Windows 8? I'll ask in new post.

Comment: but at the same time. I do want the Windows 8 client to see a pop up message from the Ubuntu Client.